# How to limit consuming of cross domain web service to certain requests

Tags: ajax, wcf, web-services, security, cross-domain

If i have a web service in .NET like `WCF` or `ASMX`, when publish this service on the server you will not be able to access it from any where else than the application that host it, unless you change the security settings to allow cross domain access .

Now any application can consume this web service if the address is known, Right ?
for example you can invoke this server web service in your local browser and see what it does...

**Question is**
How can i secure this web service ... and limit consuming to certain defined application or requests that have been predefined to the web service ?

Comment: Not sure you mean XSS... XSS refers to a security vulnerability. What are you looking to do - to me it looks like you have one domain that your website makes AJAX requests to but you now want to introduce a mobile application to to use the same API? It this actually a different domain (e.g. foo.com vs bar.com)?

Comment: XSS means cross site scripting ... yes it is a security Vulnerable  ... and what i wanted to do is to prevent anyone from consuming my web service when you know the meta data address to it (and tell me how hard is it to find HTTP requests :) on your network )

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting - that is different than allowing your web service from different applications (or domains).

Comment: possible duplicate of [RESTful web service - how to authenticate requests from other services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134082/restful-web-service-how-to-authenticate-requests-from-other-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern browsers prevent cross-domain access by default.  This can be conditionally relaxed by leveraging the the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header defined by the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) specification.  Specifically, cross-domain XHR requests from modern browsers will always include an `Origin` header, which your server code can use to filter requests based on the domain of the page making the request.  Your server can either reject the request by, for example, responding with a 401 (unauthorized) response status), or honor the request by returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the same value as the one found in the `Origin` request header.

Note, however that relaxing access to your system via CORS is - security-wise - very different from restricting access using some form of authentication.  You're relying on clients to be well behaved when declaring their origin, but that's not always a valid assumption.

Comment: CORS is about relaxing *same origin policy* on the client side, not about securing the server side. While the OP may require CORS, a server solution is still required.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add authentication to your web service. So very request to each method would be authenticated by a token sent in a cookie.

For the web site, this can use the authentication cookie that the rest of the site uses. If users have to log into the mobile application, then you would also need to authenticate them.

This would stop anyone without access to your site or mobile application being able to consume your web service.

I would also strongly advise protecting your web service and site with TLS (SSL) so everything is accessed via HTTPS.

Comment: Do you have any example of this ? Thanks

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4398/Authentication-for-Web-Services-using-SOAP-headers